# How do I fix error Syntax Error: Unexpected token '.' when running anchor test

Tags: anchor, anchor-test, javascript, typescript

I get the following error when I run `anchor test` to test my smart contract using typescript:

### Error snippet

```
    abortSignal: options?.abortSignal,
                           ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

### Full error log

```
warning: /home/darren/git/projects/github.com/tome-gg/negotiation-protocols/src/alignment-negotiation/programs/alignment-negotiation/Cargo.toml: unused manifest key: package.author
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.21s

Found a 'test' script in the Anchor.toml. Running it as a test suite!

Running test suite: "/home/darren/git/projects/github.com/tome-gg/negotiation-protocols/src/alignment-negotiation/Anchor.toml"

yarn run v1.22.19
$ /home/darren/git/projects/github.com/tome-gg/negotiation-protocols/src/alignment-negotiation/node_modules/.bin/ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 'tests/**/*.ts'

/home/darren/git/projects/github.com/tome-gg/negotiation-protocols/src/alignment-negotiation/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:2022
      abortSignal: options?.abortSignal,
                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/darren/git/projects/github.com/tome-gg/negotiation-protocols/src/alignment-negotiation/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/nodewallet.ts:2:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/darren/git/projects/github.com/tome-gg/negotiation-protocols/src/alignment-negotiation/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/index.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/darren/git/projects/github.com/tome-gg/negotiation-protocols/src/alignment-negotiation/tests/src-alignment-negotiation.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Module.m._compile (/home/darren/git/projects/github.com/tome-gg/negotiation-protocols/src/alignment-negotiation/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/home/darren/git/projects/github.com/tome-gg/negotiation-protocols/src/alignment-negotiation/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.implementationOfRequireOrImportForUnstableEsm [as requireOrImport] (/home/darren/git/projects/github.com/tome-gg/negotiation-protocols/src/alignment-negotiation/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:116:12)
    at Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (/home/darren/git/projects/github.com/tome-gg/negotiation-protocols/src/alignment-negotiation/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:103:34)
    at Mocha.loadFilesAsync (/home/darren/git/projects/github.com/tome-gg/negotiation-protocols/src/alignment-negotiation/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:448:19)
    at singleRun (/home/darren/git/projects/github.com/tome-gg/negotiation-protocols/src/alignment-negotiation/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:125:15)
    at exports.runMocha (/home/darren/git/projects/github.com/tome-gg/negotiation-protocols/src/alignment-negotiation/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:190:10)
    at Object.exports.handler (/home/darren/git/projects/github.com/tome-gg/negotiation-protocols/src/alignment-negotiation/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:374:11)
    at /home/darren/git/projects/github.com/tome-gg/negotiation-protocols/src/alignment-negotiation/node_modules/yargs/build/index.cjs:443:71
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

What does it mean? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Context

The error message specifically complains about the `.` which is the [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#browser_compatibility) feature in Javascript.

The reason why optional chaining did not make sense (i.e. SyntaxError) is because the current version of `node` I was using does not have support for Optional Chaining, because it was an old version of node.

Optional chaining was supported officially supported in ES2020.

### Solution

Use  `nvm` to use a more updated node version when running typescript/javascript programs (like `ts-mocha`, which anchor uses for running tests).

```
nvm use v16.14.0
```

### References

- [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#browser_compatibility)
- [node version manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)
- (Optional reading) [Feature proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining)